# BO Universe Designer - Where cluase for a year

Tags: where-clause, business-objects, universe

I am trying to run a query within Business Objects Universe Designer and I need help with the 'Where' clause.

I want to search for all records that have a 4 digit year (the DB column is in `YYYY`) less than or equal to 3 years from the current year.  So if the year is 2014, I would like to search for every record with a year less than or equal to 2011.

Here is my current where clause:

```
dbo.DB_TABLE.CATEGORY = 'Actual' and dbo.DB_TABLE.YR <= (convert (SMALLDATETIME, {fn CURDATE()})-3)
```

Under the 'Date' function, Universe Designer only has: `convert (SMALLDATETIME, {fn CURDATE()})`

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `yr` is just a number, you only need to extract the year from the current date:

```
dbo.DB_TABLE.YR <= datepart(year,{fn curdate()})-3
```

When writing a SQL statement in the SELECT or WHERE boxes in Designer, you are not limited to only using the functions available in the list box.  **Any** SQL that is valid for the database can be used.  The list box is only a helper, and lists commonly-used functions and statements.